# Delete massive amount of files without running out of memory

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

There is COTS app we have that creates reports and never deletes it. So we need to start cleaning it up. I started doing a `foreach` and would run out of memory on the server (36GB) when it got up to 50ish million files. After searching it seemed you could change it like so

```
Get-ChildItem -path $Path -recurse | foreach {
```

and it won't go through memory but process each item at a time. I can get to 140 million files before I run out of memory.

```
Clear-Host
#Set Age to look for
$TimeLimit = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-4)
$Path = "D:\CC\LocalStorage"

$TotalFileCount = 0
$TotalDeletedCount = 0

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | foreach {
    if ($_.LastWriteTime -le $TimeLimit) {
        $TotalDeletedCount += 1
        $_.Delete()
    }
    $TotalFileCount += 1

    $FileDiv = $TotalFileCount % 10000
    if ($FileDiv -eq 0 -and $TotalFileCount -ne 0) {
        $TF = [string]::Format('{0:N0}', $TotalFileCount)
        $TD = [string]::Format('{0:N0}', $TotalDeletedCount)
        Write-Host "Files Scanned : " -ForegroundColor Green  -NoNewline
        Write-Host "$TF" -ForegroundColor Yellow    -NoNewline
        Write-Host " Deleted: " -ForegroundColor Green  -NoNewline
        Write-Host "$TD" -ForegroundColor Yellow  
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this? My only next thought was not to use the `-Recurse` command but make my own function that calls itself for each directory.

EDIT:

I used the code provided in the first answer and it does not solve the issue. Memory is still growing.

```
$limit = (Get-Date).Date.AddMonths(-3)
$totalcount  = 0
$deletecount = 0
$Path = "D:\CC\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -File |  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } |  Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Write-Host should be changed to Write-Verbose if the goal is automation. See http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

Comment: This is a specific task for one thing. I get the purpose of Write-Verbose but since it's just me using it for quick information it's fine.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `ForEach-Object` and the pipeline should actually prevent the code from running out of memory. If you're still getting OOM exceptions I suspect that you're doing something in your code that counters this effect, which you didn't tell us about.

With that said, you should be able to clean up your data directory with something like this:

```
$limit = (Get-Date).Date.AddMonths(-4)

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -File |
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } |
  Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` switch after you verified that everything is working.

If you need the total file count and the number of deleted files, add counters like this:

```
$totalcount  = 0
$deletecount = 0

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -File |
  ForEach-Object { $totalcount++; $_ } |
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } |
  ForEach-Object { $deletecount++; $_ } |
  Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

I don't recommend printing status information to the console when you're bulk-processing large numbers of files. The output could significantly slow down the processing. If you must have that information, write it to a log file and tail that file separately.

Comment: That function is exactly like I have it. I just removed a messages I post before and after the function. As for the output I agree it would slow processing which is why I only do it every 10000 but that's just for me to keep an eye on where it is before it dies from OOM.

I will test your code soon. Will take until tomorrow since there are so many files but thank you.

Comment: Ok, So I used the first script without any modification and it still eats up memory. I can't have it run the whole folder before consuming all 36 GB of RAM

Comment: Can't reproduce. I tested the above code with 1,000,000 randomly generated files, and there was no significant increase in memory consumption.

Comment: I don't have any issues with 1 million files either it doesn't increase a lot. but 140 million take up 32 gig of ram.

Comment: Well, just delete the files in batches then. This is a one-time cleanup task after all, right?